# Alarm Clock application in android

Tags: android, alarm, wakeup

I am working on alarm clock project and I want to implement code to wake up alarm when phone is off like android built in alarm  service
is it possible to make to it ??

please answer.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Your question doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, i guess Android does not support such alarms yet. In Android alarms work only when the phone is switched on.